# CodeIgniter Join 2 columns from different tables to another different table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to select two columns from different tables: `dbusers.students.ID` and `dbusers.parents.ID`

Into another table of another database: `dbrecords.consultations.SENDER`

Which translates into CodeIgniter code as:

```
$this->dbrecords->select('consultations.*, dbusers.parents.*, dbusers.students.*');

$this->dbrecords->from('consultations');
$this->dbrecords->where('receiver', $id);
$this->dbrecords->order_by('DATE_SENT', 'DESC');
$this->dbrecords->order_by('TIME_SENT', 'DESC');

$this->dbrecords->join('sctporta_dbusers.parents', 'sctporta_dbusers.parents.ID = consultations.SENDER');
$this->dbrecords->join('sctporta_dbusers.students', 'sctporta_dbusers.students.ID = consultations.SENDER');

$query = $this->dbrecords->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

And I am getting empty results. If I try to only use two tables, it works. But I want to join the two tables into another table.

Comment: u need to add database alias on all location like `$this->dbrecords->from('consultations');`

Comment: How to do that in CodeIgniter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159130/codeignitor-multiple-database-join

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159618/join-query-of-two-databases-in-codeigniter

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416794/joining-tables-from-two-databases-using-codeigniter